# MessagePackのシリアライズ・デシリアライズ時間がJsonよりが遅くなる

Tags: c#, unity3d, json

API通信を高速化するためMessagePackを使用したいと考えており
シリアライズ・デシリアライズの速度がどれだけ違うかを
MessagePackとJSONを使用して、
下記処理で速度比較を行っています。

**■追記**
**計測に誤りがあったのでソースコード書き直し、計測値を再計測

シリアライズ後のサイズを追加**

**データ作成→時間計測→シリアライズ→時間計測→デシリアライズ→時間計測**

**■使用したMsgPack**

https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-cli/releases

上記URLのバージョン**0.62**内にあるzipファイルを展開して
　**unity3d**フォルダ内にある**MsgPack.dll**を使用しています。

**■使用したJson**

MiniJSON

**■テストケース**
　１：
　（0-10000までのintのListを１００回シリアライズ・デシリアライズした平均値）を
　　Android実機で確認

２：
　（0-10000までのstringのListを１００回シリアライズ・デシリアライズした平均値）を
　　Android実機で確認

**■テスト結果**
　■ケース１
　　MsgPack（Array）：
　　　シリアライズ後のバイト数：29747
　　　シリアライズ時間　：24.6msec
　　　デシリアライズ時間：165.2msec

Json：
　　　シリアライズ後のバイト数：48891
　　　シリアライズ時間　：31.1msec
　　　デシリアライズ時間：74.7msec

■ケース２
　　MsgPack（Array）：
　　　シリアライズ後のバイト数：48893
　　　シリアライズ時間　：37.6 msec
　　　デシリアライズ時間：277.0 msec
　　Json：
　　　シリアライズ後のバイト数：68891
　　　シリアライズ時間　：22.2 msec
　　　デシリアライズ時間：57.5 msec

**■ソースコード**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MiniJSON;
using MsgPack;
using MsgPack.Serialization;
using System.Linq;

public class MsgPackAndJsonCompare : MonoBehaviour {

public int SampleCount = 100;

private string MsgLog = "";
private int SampleIndex = 0;


List<long> ArrayListLong = new List<long>();
List<string> ArrayListString = new List<string>();



/// <summary>
/// intデータ作成処理
/// </summary>
public void OnClickArrayInt()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        ArrayListLong.Add(i);
    }
    Debug.Log("OnClickArrayInt End");
}


/// <summary>
/// Stringデータ作成処理
/// </summary>
public void OnClickArrayString()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        ArrayListString.Add(i.ToString());
    }
    Debug.Log("OnClickArrayString End");

}


/// <summary>
/// 100回ループするテスト開始
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sendMode"></param>
public void OnClickCompare(int sendMode)
{
    SampleIndex = 0;

    for (int i = SampleIndex; i < SampleCount; i++)
    {
        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",LoopCnt=" + i.ToString();
        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",StartTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

        MainFunc(sendMode);

        MsgLog = MsgLog + " ,EndTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "\n";
    }

    Debug.Log("Function End");


}

/// <summary>
/// メイン処理
/// </summary>
/// <param name="compareMode"></param>
private void MainFunc(int compareMode)
{
    // ArrayInt-MsgPack
    if (compareMode == 0)
    {
        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",シリアライズStartTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        // Create serializer instance.
        var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Get<List<long>>();
        serializer.Pack(stream, ArrayListLong);

        //long datalen = stream.Length;

        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",シリアライズEndTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        stream.Position = 0;
        List<long> deserializedObject = serializer.Unpack(stream);
        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",デシリアライズEndTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    }
    // ArrayInt-Json
    else if (compareMode == 1)
    {
        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",シリアライズStartTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        string serialized = Json.Serialize(ArrayListLong);

        int ilenb = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetByteCount(serialized);

        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",シリアライズEndTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        List<System.Object> deserializedDoubleList = Json.Deserialize(serialized) as List<System.Object>;
        List<long> longList = deserializedDoubleList.OfType<long>().ToList();
        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",デシリアライズEndTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

    }
    // ArrayString-MsgPack
    else if (compareMode == 2)
    {
        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",シリアライズStartTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        // Create serializer instance.
        var serializer = MessagePackSerializer.Get<List<string>>();
        serializer.Pack(stream, ArrayListString);

        long datalen = stream.Length;

        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",シリアライズEndTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        stream.Position = 0;
        List<string> deserializedObject = serializer.Unpack(stream);
        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",デシリアライズEndTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    }
    // ArrayString-Json
    else if (compareMode == 3)
    {
        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",シリアライズStartTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        string serialized = Json.Serialize(ArrayListString);

        int ilenb = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(65001).GetByteCount(serialized);

        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",シリアライズEndTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        List<System.Object> deserializedDoubleList = Json.Deserialize(serialized) as List<System.Object>;
        List<string> longList = deserializedDoubleList.OfType<string>().ToList();
        MsgLog = MsgLog + ",デシリアライズEndTime=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

    }
}


public void OnclickLog()
{
    StartCoroutine(LogDisp());

}


IEnumerator LogDisp()
{
    string[] LogArray = MsgLog.Split('\n');

    int maxloop = LogArray.Length;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < maxloop)
    {
        Debug.Log("Log=" + LogArray[i]);

        yield return 0;

        i++;

    }
}
```

■問題点
　ネットなどで情報を集めているとMessagePackの方が早いという記述が
　多くみられるのですが、私のソースではMessagePackで処理するよりも
　JSONの方が速度が速いため、やり方が間違っているのではと疑っています。

Answer (score 1):

シリアライズとは入力データをバイナリなどに変換することです。
デシリアライズとはその逆でバイナリなどを入力データの形に戻すことです。

`MessagePackSerializer`は`List<int>`をシリアライズし、また`List<int>`へとデシリアライズしています。
しかし`Json.Serialize`は`List<int>`をシリアライズはしますが、`Json.Deserialize`は`List<int>`へとは戻しておらず、JSON文字列をデコードしかしていません。（返されるのは`object[]`かな？）

ですので対等な比較になっていません。

---

さっぱり通じていないようなので追記します。
`MessagePackSerializer`は条件を満たせば任意の型対応しています。例えば

```
public struct Color {
    public int R;
    public int G;
    public int B;
    public override string ToString() { return "Hoge"; }
}
```

を渡しても型を解釈し、パブリックプロパティをシリアライズしますし、デシリアライズ時には各プロパティ値を復元したものを返します。
対して`MiniJSON`は、型を維持しません。[未知の型に対してはToString()](https://gist.github.com/darktable/1411710#file-minijson-cs-L542)した結果をシリアライズしますし、数値は`double`や`int64`にデシリアライズします。
結果、`MiniJSON`で上記`Color`をシリアライズするとJSON文字列は `"Hoge"` になりますし、デシリアライズしても文字列しか得られません。

ですので対等な比較になっていません。

Comment: なるほどたしかに、おっしゃる通りです。　１段階処理が足りないですね
　var型で受けた中身は元の型にはなってないです。　処理を加えて計測し直してみます。

Comment: OfType<long>().ToList()を使用してList<System.object>から List<Long>などの元の型へ戻す処理を入れてみたのですが、まだJSONの方がMessagePackより優秀なのでデータサイズを増やすなりして計測したいと思います。
また、MessagePackのデシリアライズ時間が以上に長いためこのあたりを調査します。

Comment: たしかにデータクラス等はMiniJsonでは戻せないのでKey−Valueのようにする必要があるとは思いますが、List<string>やList<long>などはJson.DeserializeしたものをLinqなどを使用して元の型ように読めるデータに変換すれば要件を満たしているように思います。　実際にList<string> longList = deserializedDoubleList.OfType<string>().ToList();　で取得したリストをループでログ表示してみましたが中身は元のデータと一致していました。List<long> longList　についても同様に元のデータと一致しました。